# Turning hashtags to links in place, in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, replace, hashtag

I am trying to convert hashtags into links within a micropost. I have implemented a gem called simple_hashtag which seems to work for the linking aspect of this. However, the gem works by extracting hashtags from the post and displaying them in their own loop. So, for example if my Micropost was:

```
    Today I went #snowboarding, it was #awesome
```

The code to extract the tags is done as a loop, which means it has to be done outside of the content.

```
    <p><%= micropost.content %></p>
    <ul>
        <% micropost.hashtags.each do |hashtag| %>
            <li><%= link_to hashtag.name, hashtag_path(hashtag.name) %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
```

This leaves the finished view looking like:

```
    Today I went #snowboarding, it was #awesome
    - snowboarding
    - awesome
```

Is it possible to have the code scan the content and replace the hashtags with the links in place? I am wondering if there is a way to maybe collect the hashtags, convert them into links and then replace them in the content?

I know I can scan the content and find the hashes using the following:

```
    <% content = micropost.content %>
    <% hashes = content.scan(/#\w+/) %>
    <% hashes.each do |hash| %>
        <%= hash %>
    <% end %>
```

I would then like to use something like `hash.gsub!` or even Javascript, to replace the hashtags in the content with the links rather than having them listed below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a helper for this with something like:

```
<%= render_with_hashtags(micropost.content) %>
```

in your view, and code like this:

```
class MicropostHelper
  def render_with_hashtags(content)
    content_words = content.split(" ")
    content_with_links = content_words.map do |word| 
      if word.contains?("#")
        link_to hashtag.name, hashtag_path(hashtag.name)
      else
        word
      end
    end

    content_with_links.join(" ")
  end
end
```

so, we iterate on each word in the content, replacing the hashtags by links at leaving the rest "as is".

Comment: This was super helpful! I had to use .html_safe on the render, as it was just showing the raw html. I also had to link_to word instead of the hashtag.name, and this meant stripping the # off before it created the link with >  word = word.tr('#', '') - But its working like a charm now! Thanks so much for your help Martin

Comment: Glad it was useful. Agreed, my code was a bit too much "pseudo code", especially regarding the tags. Good catch with the "raw/html_safe" part, should have added it. Happy coding!

Comment: This will break formatting (careful when using with `simple_format` for example).

Answer (score 9):

I would do it using regex, instead of splitting and joining the text

```
def render_with_hashtags(text)
  text.gsub(/(?:#(\w+))/) {hashtag_link($1)}
end
def hashtag_link(hash)
  link_to "##{hash}", hashtag_path(hash)
end
```

You can add `html_safe` inside the method if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a try of this also, is there advantages to using regex?

Comment: I think it would be faster ( and smaller ) but you could benchmark it if you want to check if it is or not.